# How to remove this?

Tags: pantheon-terminal

I get so packets, so what...Don't know what the package? How to remove?[image]

Comment: please provide more details : command you used ..

Comment: actuaily, if knew commands - threre is no problem)

Comment: i just wanna my terminal back(reinstal didn't hel)

Comment: part solved - deletet sceenfetch from ~/.bashrc

Comment: If you want to reinstall terminal : `sudo apt-get install --reinstall pantheon-terminal`

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the answer to this question, hidden in the comments, was to remove the `screenfetch` command from `~/.bashrc`